# About Variable-Size Stack Frames, about the alignment of stack frame，an example from CSAPP

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, att

**C code:**

```
long vframe(long n, long idx, long *q) {
    long i;
    long *p[n];
    p[0] = &i;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = q;

    return *p[idx];
}
```

**Portions of generated assembly code:**

```
long vframe(long n, long idx, long *q)

n in %rdi, idx in %rsi, q in %rdx
Only portions of code shown
vframe:
pushq   %rbp            Save old %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp      Set frame pointer
subq    $16, %rsp       Allocate space for i (%rsp = s1)
leaq    22(,%rdi,8), %rax
andq    $-16, %rax
subq    %rax, %rsp      Allocate space for array p (%rsp = s2)
leaq    7(%rsp), %rax
shrq    $3, %rax
leaq    0(,%rax,8), %r8     Set %r8 to &p[0]
movq    %r8, %rcx       Set %rcx to &p[0] (%rcx = p)
...
Code for initialization loop
i in %rax and on stack, n in %rdi, p in %rcx, q in %rdx
.L3:                  loop:
movq    %rdx, (%rcx,%rax,8) Set p[i] to q
addq    $1, %rax        Increment i
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)      Store on stack
.L2:
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax      Retrieve i from stack
cmpq    %rdi, %rax      Compare i:n
jl  .L3         If <, goto loop
...
Code for function exit
leave               Restore %rbp and %rsp
ret             Return
```

---

In the book the author says：

The `leaq` instruction in

```
leaq    22(,%rdi,8), %rax
```

computes the value `8n + 22`, which is then rounded down to the nearest multiple of `16` by the `andq` instruction in

```
andq    $-16, %rax
```

The resulting value will be `8n + 8` when *`n` is odd* and `8n + 16` when *`n` is even*, and this value is subtracted from `s1` to give `s2`.

What puzzles me is `8n + 22`. why must it be `22`, not `16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23`?

Comment: It does not have to be 22 since the `and` will chop off the low 4 bits anyway.

Comment: Any number greater than 15 and less than 23 can work？gcc just happed to choose the number 22 ？

Comment: GCC7 does actually do this  https://godbolt.org/z/Hedvqs.  You'd expect `(n+15)&-16` to round the size up to a multiple of 16.  Note that the ABI requires variable-length arrays to be 16-byte aligned.

Comment: Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/69605779/9304999 Read @NateEldredge‘s comments.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem when I read here now.

and I try to complie the source code by `clang` with command:

> clang -Og -S source.c -o source.s

in both platform ubuntu18.04 and windows 10,

the assembly file shows:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $16, %rsp
movq    %rsp, %r8
movq    %rsp, %r9
leaq    15(,%rdi,8), %r10
andq    $-16, %r10
movq    %r9, %rax
     ...
```

`clang` choose 15 even not from 16 to 23,

I read [The x86-64 psABI version 1.0](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf),

in section `3.2.2 The Stack Frame`:

> The end of the input argument area shall be aligned on a 16 (32 or 64, if
>   __m256 or __m512 is passed on stack) byte boundary. In other words, the value
>   (%rsp + 8) is always a multiple of 16 (32 or 64) when control is transferred to
>   the function entry point. The stack pointer, %rsp, always points to the end of the
>   latest allocated stack frame.

so I think the number is `22` or `15` is not important thing,

the number just leads to the size of `e1` and `e2`

`clang` choose `15`, then when `n` is even, `e1` and `e2` will be less than `gcc` version,

the key point is to guard 16 bytes align for the end of a stack frame,

or the value of `s2 - s1` in a variable-size stack frame.

Comment: How does this answer you posted answer the question?  Also, the ABI requires variable-length arrays to be aligned by 16; that's what `(n + 15) & -16` is doing.

Comment: The point is not 16 bytes align rather than the number which is plus `8n`, in your comment, `n` instead.